# How can there be AES-256-GCM, when GCM is defined for 128-sized blocks?

Tags: aes, block-cipher, gcm, blocksize

In both node.js and OpenSSL, I am seeing cipher "aes-256-gcm".

However, in [NIST Special Publication 800-38D, that defines GCM](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38D/SP-800-38D.pdf), I am reading:

> The underlying block cipher shall be approved, the block size shall be 128 bits, and the key size shall be at least 128 bits.

How is this possible?

edit:

I see a similar question has been asked already - [GCM encryption for 256-bit and 512-bit block ciphers](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14524/gcm-encryption-for-256-bit-and-512-bit-block-ciphers) - but that one is more theoretical question, while in openssl, there is a practical implementation.

Those answers imply that it might be insecure. Is it true, and are the openssl implementations inherently insecure?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

AES has a block-size of 128 bits in all its variants. The number in AES-128/192/256 is the key-size. Rijndael, the block-cipher that became AES, also supports 256 bit blocks, but that part was not standardized as AES.

Since the block-size is 128 bits, GCM works exactly the same way for AES-256 as it does for AES-128.